# Why git clone git:// is not working

Tags: git, github, ssh

```
// This works
git clone https://github.com/foreverjs/forever.git

// This one also works
git clone git@github.com:foreverjs/forever.git

// This one didn't work
git clone git://github.com/foreverjs/forever.git
```

The error message for the third one is:

```
Cloning into 'forever'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

As far as I know, git clone over SSH or HTTPS is more restricted than `git://` protocol. I'm really confused why I got the this error message since `git://` protocol doesn't even require for authentication.

Is github only allowed git clone over SSH or HTTPS now or I missed something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gitconfig file in my local computer caused this problem, I found the following two lines in ~/.gitconfig file:

```
[url "ssh://"]
    insteadOf = git://
```

If I removed these two lines, the git:// protocol will not run over SSH so there will be no more permission issues

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/591301/500837 will replace all git:// by https://

Comment: That helped! For some weird reason, I had the following two lines in my .gitconfig file: `[url "git@github. om:"]` `insteadOf = https://github.com/`. And I always wondered why it tried to contact "github. om". Strange ^^

Answer (score 0):

It works for me just fine:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/foreverjs/forever.git
Cloning into 'forever'...
remote: Counting objects: 3258, done.
remote: Total 3258 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 3258
Receiving objects: 100% (3258/3258), 782.12 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1341/1341), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

Do you have your public key set up properly?

But `git://` is different protocol, as mentioned in the manual page:

> - `git:` the anonymous git protocol over a direct TCP connection (or proxy, if configured)

It is insecure (no encryption) so not recommended to use.

> Is github only allowed git clone over SSH or HTTPS now or I missed something here?

The preferred way is to use SSH or HTTPS because you are always connecting over insecure Internet (unless you are in the data-center of GitHub -- unlikely). The `git` protocol can come handy in intranets or local networks which you trust. Also note that

> a URL like "git://example.org/path/to/repo.git" will be rewritten to "ssh://example.org/path/to/repo.git" for pushes, but pulls will still use the original URL.

Comment: I checked from github and verified that the public key was set up correctly. As you can see, there's no issue with git clone via SSH and HTTPS. Still not understand what the real issue here

Comment: @ChuangFu Is your network filtered? The git protocol server listens on port 9418; if you cannot connect outbound to that port, that would explain why it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with a never ending console print with git bash.

In my case, I removed all Git related entries in the windows credential manager and the my .gitconfig and afterwards I used the clone functionality of [Github Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/).

Within Github Desktop I had to reset my credentials (username and developer token) and it worked for me again.